# Access Jira on VirtualBox from host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, jira

I'm developing a plugin for JIRA and installed the Atlassian SDK on a Xubuntu 14.04 guest on a Win7 host with VirtualBox. On my VM I can access my JIRA instance via localhost:2990/jira or my given IP adress 10.0.2.15:2990/jira.
Now I need to access the JIRA instance from my Win7 host. How can I achieve this?

Comment: reconfigure the VM to use Bridged networking, and set the VM to use a static IP in the range of your LAN network. The other alternative is to create NAT port forward rules in VirtualBox, that forward TCP\2990 to the Hosts connection. Its a lot easier to use bridged networking though.

Comment: This was a good hint, thank you for that. I've changed my VM to use bridged networking. After that, I needed to disable DHCP and give the guest an IP adress manually. It's working now :)